# How to use AJAX in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax

I am working on one custom module and i need child categories when any ID is clicked. Loading is handle by ajax. I am not aware of ajax in Magento 2. Can anybody give me small demo of ajax in Magento 2..

Answer (score 1):

**1st Method:-**
You can use it instead of Ajax to Get Sub Category List Of Particular Parent Category In Magento:-

```
<select id="category" class="myinput-text required-entry widthinput" name="category">
<?php
  $parentid=5; // parent id which you want sub category
  $categories=explode(',',Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentid)->getChildren());
  foreach($categories as $cat){ 
     $category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $category->getId();?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

OR

```
/* Load category by id*/
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);


/*Returns comma separated ids*/
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

//Print out categories string
#print_r($subcats);

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive())
  {
    $caturl     = $_category->getURL();
    $catname     = $_category->getName();
    if($_category->getImageUrl())
    {
      $catimg     = $_category->getImageUrl();
    }
    echo '<h2><a href="'.$caturl.'" title="View the products for this category"><img src="'.$catimg.'" alt="" />'.$catname.'</a></h2>';
  }
}
?>
```

**2nd Method:-**
You need to add a dependency to your class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory.`

Like this

```
protected $categoryCollectionFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    ...
}
public function getDescendants($category, $levels = 2)
{
    if ((int)$levels < 1) {
        $levels = 1;
    }
    $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create()
          ->addPathsFilter($category->getPath().'/') 
          ->addLevelFilter($category->getLevel() + $levels);
    return $collection;
}
```

now you just need to call the method `getDescendants` with the `$category` object as parameter and the number of levels you need for subcategories (2 in your case).

Comment: Thank u Vishal for u r answer .But I was looking for Magento 2

Answer (score 1):

here is sample code make ajax call with jquery

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
  $( "#search" ).click(function() {

    var searchval=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "<?php  echo $block->getUrl('test/test/test'); ?>",
      data: { q: searchval },
      dataType: "json"
    })
  .done(function( msg ) {

     // do here  


  });

  });

</script>
```